# Running into CUDA out of memory

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, conv-neural-network

I am trying to evaluate MAE for images using a CNN model with pre-trained weights and after 240th iteration I run into this error (in the image)

[image: Error and Code]

```
mae = 0
for i in range(len(img_paths)):
    img = 255.0 * F.to_tensor(Image.open(img_paths[i]).convert('RGB'))

    img[0,:,:]=img[0,:,:]-92.8207477031
    img[1,:,:]=img[1,:,:]-95.2757037428
    img[2,:,:]=img[2,:,:]-104.877445883
    img = img.cuda()
    #img = transform(Image.open(img_paths[i]).convert('RGB')).cuda()
    gt_file = h5py.File(img_paths[i].replace('.jpg','.h5').replace('images','ground'),'r')
    groundtruth = np.asarray(gt_file['density'])
    output = model(img.unsqueeze(0))
    del img
    mae += float(abs(output.detach().cpu().sum().numpy()-np.sum(groundtruth)))
    print (i,mae)
print (mae/len(img_paths))
```

However , the funny thing is , the exact same code threw no errors/warnings about memory or anything at all just a few weeks ago. I havent changed anything. But yesterday when I tried to run it , it threw this memory run out error. The batch size is 1. I tried the solutions from other similar threads but nothing seems to be working.
I am not very familiar with using pytorch . So can anyone suggest what to do?

One other thing I observed is , when the code runs into this error and stop , running the command - nvidia-smi- shows the following warning :

`WARNING: infoROM is corrupted at gpu 0000:01:00.0`

[image: Screenshot]

This warning doesnt show up when I reboot my system. Appears only after this code is run. Does this mean my Graphics Card (GTX-1650) is damaged?

Comment: Try tu update Nvidia drivers, Cuda and CUDNN.

Comment: @LouisLac - Updated my Nvidia driver . Still getting the same error. What I fail to understand is how can the same program which ran perfectly a few weeks ago is now failing. Kindly suggest anything else if you know.